# Can I import custom classes into Use cases of the Domain layer?

Tags: android, kotlin, import, use-case, clean-architecture

When I want to follow the **Android Clean Architecture**,
For example,
I create `Category` as Enum class used on the UI layer for a `Todo` item's field.
Thus, it is considered to using on the UI layer model(`Todo`) but also the Domain layer model(`TodoEntity`).
When this situation, Can I import the `Category` into UseCase?
In addition, I wonder if it is possible to create a class with data formatting logic of similar logic used in both UI layer and domain layer, or write or import very complex UI layer model processing in UseCase.
What standards are there on this?

Answer (score 0):

According to data flow in Clean Architecture

[image]

UseCases should not use models from UI layer. You can create CategoryModel class in data/domain layer, and then use it from UI layer or map it into similar model from UI layer.

Comment: Category is not model. it is just enum class kind of value like todo(model)’s field and it is used some ui layer function and domain layer function. when this situation. can i use category on both layers?

Comment: In this case it doesn't matter enum or data class. Just store it in the domain layer, because UI layer should depend on domain layer, but domain layer shouldn't know anything about UI.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: So what about custom classes like formatUtil? The formatUtil I'm talking about includes a function that returns various kinds of strings using, for example, dateformat. Can this be used for both UI Layer and Domain Layer?

Comment: As soon as UI layer depends on Domain Layer, you store util classes in Domain and you can easily use them from both UI and Domain. If you store this classes in UI, you can't use them from Domain because Domain shouldn't know anything about UI. And of course you can have UI-specific util classes in UI layer, but they should only be used from UI layer. Moreover, UI layer shouldn't make any data transformations, it should be as stupid as possible. UI layer just visually represents data, Domain layer should make all data transformations